# Convertion of excel file with point data into .cxt file

Tags: conversion, microsoft-excel

How can I convert a **excel file** (.xls extension) with point climatic data into **.cxt file** which is a free format text file. My intention is to calculate evopotranspiration using ETo software. But when importing climatic data, the file with extention .cxt is required. I hope someone can help me to convert excel to .cxt file.

Thanks all

Comment: @user3063, what happens if you rename the .xls to .cxt manually in Windows Explorer? Can ETo software see or open the .cxt file?

Comment: @ user3063 -- Good suggestion.  That would be the first thing I would try.  Copy the file and change the extension.

Comment: Could you provide more information on the cxt-format, maybe an example? I googled it a bit didn't find anything that seemed to be a free format text file.

Comment: I found some information about the .cxt format in [this PDF](http://www.fao.org/nr/water/docs/ReferenceManualETo.pdf)

Comment: Siim K's PDF provides a lot of information about the calculations but little about the file formats. There appear to be three extensions: CXT, DSC and DAT. All are text files which are either tab delimited or fixed length. If the worksheets are in just the right format, Excel export might work. Otherwise this is a VBA task.

Answer (score 2):

I'm sure you fixed this problem, but I'd like to leave this note for future users.

1 - Download EditPad Lite (free text editor - http://www.editpadlite.com/),

2 - copy the data from excel to the editor,

3 - save the file, in the "save as type" select "Unspecified file type (*.*)",

4 - go to the folder and change manually the extension to .CXT,

5 - Open the ETo calculator and import the file.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser!  Thanks for posting this solution, to help out anyone else who might come looking.

Answer (score 0):

Per the [documentation](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/file-formats-that-are-supported-in-excel-HP010014103.aspx#BMexcelformats) the `.cxt` file format is not supported by **MicroSoft Excel**. You will have to look for an add-in or external file converter.

Answer (score 0):

Since .cxt is just space delimited with the order of the columns pre-determined you could to Save As...>.prn file. .prn files are space delimited/fixed width. Then you can change the extension in Windows Explorer.

If you need to do this action a lot it can all be automated of course.